# JSON object returned without name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get the following JSON returned from the server

```
{
    "someStuff": {
        "": {
            "foo": 0
        },
        "moreStuff": {
            "foo": 2
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the first node in someStuff is not named.

Is there a way to handle this is JavaScript, eg, how can I select a node which has no name?

I know that the proper solution is to name the node in the code which generates the JSON, but I am looking for a dirty fix till I can contact the developer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.foo` is the same as `["foo"]`, so use `[]` whenever the name is not an identifier.

```
myObjectFromJSON.someStuff[""].foo
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
data.someStuff[''].foo
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GSWg9/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){

  var data={ "someStuff": {
                             "": { "foo": 0 },
                             "moreStuff": {"foo": 2 }
                           }
           }

    $.each(data.someStuff,function(index,item){

         alert(item.foo);
    });

});
```

Sample :  http://jsfiddle.net/kshyju/hURDH/4/

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use the [] operator like in the example below:

```
a = $.parseJSON('\
    {\
        "someStuff": {\
            "": {\
                "foo": 0\
            },\
            "moreStuff": {\
                "foo": 2\
            }\
        }\
    }\
');
a.someStuff[''].foo === 0  // returns true
```